# NextJs Hydration vs "use client"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, next.js13

I'm new to NextJs and trying to understand the core features.

As far as I know default behavior of NextJs components are **server-side** and uses **Hydration** to make the app interactable right after showing up the pre-rendered HTML on the server.

Later on, they brought a feature to run the both server and client side rendering types together and just writing "use client" at the top of compenent is enough to make that compenent client-side.

My question is why they needed to add "use client" even though there is **Hydration** exists. Why we would need **client-side** if we can make the the non-interactive parts interactive with **Hydration** ?

Could someone explain and would be good if i can get scenerio to understand better.

Answer (score 1):

[from here](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/client-components)

> "use client" is used to declare a boundary between a Server and Client
> Component modules. This means that by defining a "use client" in a
> file, all other modules imported into it, including child components,
> are considered part of the client bundle.
>
> using onClick and useState in a nested component (toggle.js) will
> cause an error if the "use client" directive is not defined. This is
> because, by default, the components are rendered on the server where
> these APIs are not available. By defining the "use client" directive
> in toggle.js, you can tell React to render the component and its
> children on the client, where the APIs are available.

server side components are created on the server and then sent to the browser in a serialized format. no libraries are sent to the client. you wont see the server components inside client bundle. Also, server components can render client components. [from here](https://www.webscope.io/blog/server-components-vs-ssr) this is an example of serialized server components

```
M1:{"id":"./src/SearchField.client.js","chunks":["client5"],"name":""}
M2:{"id":"./src/EditButton.client.js","chunks":["client1"],"name":""}
S3:"react.suspense"
J0:["$","div",null,{"className":"main","children":[["$","section",null,{"className":"col sidebar","children":[["$","section",null,{"className":"sidebar-header","children":[["$","img",null,{"className":"logo","src":"logo.svg","width":"22px","height":"20px","alt":"","role":"presentation"}],["$","strong",null,{"children":"React Notes"}]]}],["$","section",null,{"className":"sidebar-menu","role":"menubar","children":[["$","@1",null,{}],["$","@2",null,{"noteId":null,"children":"New"}]]}],["$","nav",null,{"children":["$","$3",null,{"fallback":["$","div",null,{"children":["$","ul",null,{"className":"notes-list skeleton-container","children":[["$","li",null,{"className":"v-stack","children":["$","div",null,{"className":"sidebar-note-list-item skeleton","style":{"height":"5em"}}]}],["$","li",null,{"className":"v-stack","children":["$","div",null,{"className":"sidebar-note-list-item skeleton","style":{"height":"5em"}}]}],["$","li",null,{"className":"v-stack","children":["$","div",null,{"className":"sidebar-note-list-item skeleton","style":{"height":"5em"}}]}]]}]}],"children":"@4"}]}]]}],["$","section","null",{"className":"col note-viewer","children":["$","$3",null,{"fallback":["$","div",null,{"className":"note skeleton-container","role":"progressbar","aria-busy":"true","children":[["$","div",null,{"className":"note-header","children":[["$","div",null,{"className":"note-title skeleton","style":{"height":"3rem","width":"65%","marginInline":"12px 1em"}}],["$","div",null,{"className":"skeleton skeleton--button","style":{"width":"8em","height":"2.5em"}}]]}],["$","div",null,{"className":"note-preview","children":[["$","div",null,{"className":"skeleton v-stack","style":{"height":"1.5em"}}],["$","div",null,{"className":"skeleton v-stack","style":{"height":"1.5em"}}],["$","div",null,{"className":"skeleton v-stack","style":{"height":"1.5em"}}],["$","div",null,{"className":"skeleton v-stack","style":{"height":"1.5em"}}],["$","div",null,{"className":"skeleton v-stack","style":{"height":"1.5em"}}]]}]]}],"children":["$","div",null,{"className":"note--empty-state","children":["$","span",null,{"className":"note-text--empty-state","children":"Click a note on the left to view something! "}]}]}]}]]}]
M5:{"id":"./src/SidebarNote.client.js","chunks":["client6"],"name":""}
J4:["$","ul",null,{"className":"notes-list","children":[["$","li","1",{"children":["$","@5",null,{"id":1,"title":"Meeting Notes","expandedChildren":["$","p",null,{"className":"sidebar-note-excerpt","children":"This is an example note. It contains Markdown!"}],"children":["$","header",null,{"className":"sidebar-note-header","children":[["$","strong",null,{"children":"Meeting Notes"}],["$","small",null,{"children":"12/30/20"}]]}]}]}],["$","li","2",{"children":["$","@5",null,{"id":2,"title":"A note with a very long title because sometimes you need more words","expandedChildren":["$","p",null,{"className":"sidebar-note-excerpt","children":"You can write all kinds of amazing notes in this app! These note live on the server in the notes..."}],"children":["$","header",null,{"className":"sidebar-note-header","children":[["$","strong",null,{"children":"A note with a very long title because sometimes you need more words"}],["$","small",null,{"children":"12/30/20"}]]}]}]}],["$","li","3",{"children":["$","@5",null,{"id":3,"title":"I wrote this note today","expandedChildren":["$","p",null,{"className":"sidebar-note-excerpt","children":"It was an excellent note."}],"children":["$","header",null,{"className":"sidebar-note-header","children":[["$","strong",null,{"children":"I wrote this note today"}],["$","small",null,{"children":"12/30/20"}]]}]}]}],["$","li","4",{"children":["$","@5",null,{"id":4,"title":"Make a thing","expandedChildren":["$","p",null,{"className":"sidebar-note-excerpt","children":"It's very easy to make some words bold and other words italic with Markdown. You can even link to React's..."}],"children":["$","header",null,{"className":"sidebar-note-header","children":[["$","strong",null,{"children":"Make a thing"}],["$","small",null,{"children":"12/30/20"}]]}]}]}],["$","li","6",{"children":["$","@5",null,{"id":6,"title":"Test Noteeeeeeeasd","expandedChildren":["$","p",null,{"className":"sidebar-note-excerpt","children":"Test note's text"}],"children":["$","header",null,{"className":"sidebar-note-header","children":[["$","strong",null,{"children":"Test Noteeeeeeeasd"}],["$","small",null,{"children":"11/29/22"}]]}]}]}],["$","li","7",{"children":["$","@5",null,{"id":7,"title":"asdasdasd","expandedChildren":["$","p",null,{"className":"sidebar-note-excerpt","children":"asdasdasd"}],"children":["$","header",null,{"className":"sidebar-note-header","children":[["$","strong",null,{"children":"asdasdasd"}],["$","small",null,{"children":"11/29/22"}]]}]}]}]]}]
```

this is just a JSON format. server component has already been executed on the server. now we have to bring a life into this JSON data. this process is called `hydration` which refers to the process of adding interactivity to a static HTML document. why this hydration is necessary:

- The server sends serialized JSON representing the initial state of server-rendered components. This approach allows the page to be quickly displayed to the user without waiting for all JavaScript to download, parse, and execute.
- While the static page can display content, it lacks the interactivity of a fully functional web application. The serialized JSON contains the state and structure needed to reinitialize the client-side application or components. By "hydrating" the page, you attach event listeners and other interactive features to the static content, making it responsive to user actions (remember server components can render cleint component).
- Hydration ensures that the client-side app can start from the same state as the server-rendered output.

Comment: I am also learning nextjs, and wondering can we have some functions that can be executed on both the server and client, would not want to write the same functions for both client and server - some kind of sharing between methods and variables ..?

Comment: if your function is not using client side specific or server side specific code, you can use. for example you cannot use `fs` on client side so if your funtion is using `fs` this can be executed only on the server

Comment: @Yilmaz I was under the impression that server components are rendered on the server and the HTML is ready to be consumed by the client, if so, what is the need for the serialized JSON to "hydrate"?

Also, in RSC is it the correct mental model:
1. Server components are "hydrated" via the JSON that is sent to the client
2. Client components are hydrated via JavaScript sent to the client

Comment: @Yazid I added explanation to the answer